# confuse about number compare in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison

The code is simple:

```
    var i = 0.5;
    if (i < 0) {
        console.log('small');
    } else {
        console.log('big');                    
    }
```

but the result is `big!`, what's wrong about my code?

Comment: Uhm, `0.5` is greater than `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The else part of your if-statement evaluates `i >= 0`. And `0.5 >= 0`.

Perhaps you wanted to write:

```
if (i >= 0 and i < 1) {
    console.log('small');
}
```

But I don't know what you would consider small ;-)

Answer (score 2):

there is nothing wrong in your code, lets take a deep look on your 'if' condition, you will get the answer that **0.5 > 0**

you may be want to write this

```
 var i = 0.5;
        if (i > 0) {
            console.log('big');
        } else {
            console.log('small');                    
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code logic is completely right...

```
0.5 is greater than 0
```